# How Java Antlr4 not be greedy with STRING_LITERAL containing \"?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I've a simple grammar like this

```
"STRING_LITERAL"(, "STRING_LITERAL")?
```

In lexer.g4, I define STRING_LITERAL like this

```
STRING_LITERAL: '"'[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&.+-^_{}:\\\" ]+'"';
```

However, it seems it will ignore the comma (",") between 2 words, as with this input test: "abc", "\"cde\""
Anltr4 will read both of these STRING_LITERALs as 1 text instead of 2 texts

```
List<TerminalNode> params = ctx.STRING_LITERAL(); // Only have 1 String element ("abc", "\"cde\"")
```

How can I use antr4 with \" in STRING_LIERAL and split it by the comma (,) then params will contains 2 element ("abc" and "\"cde\"") instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `'"' ('\\"'|.)*? '"'` as my STRING lexer rule and then use this within a params definition:

```
actionExpressions
    : exp += expression (COMMA exp += expression)*
    ;
```

The `expression` could be anything like integer, boolean, strings, IDs and so on. You shouldn't try to integrate the splitting within the STRING literal definition. A string is just a sequence of characters.

In my lexer rule the ? is "handling" the non-greediness.